# How to add a reference to model?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am new to node js, and I am doing a project. I want to have a reference of a model in another model. these are the models

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

const bloodStockSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    bloodType: { type: String, required: true },
    bloodAvailable: { type: String, required: true },
    bloodUsed: { type: String, required: true },
    branchId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Branch", required: true }}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("BloodStock", bloodStockSchema);
```

and this is the other model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const branchSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    branchName: { type: String, required: true },
    officeTelephone: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    city: { type: String, required: true },
    subCity: { type: String, required: true },
    zone: { type: String, required: true },
    wereda: { type: String, required: true },
    kebele: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Branch", branchSchema);
```

what I wanted to get is the `branchId`. This is how i tried to get it:

```
let Branch = mongoose.model('Branch');
let branchId = Branch._id;
```

and another try:

```
let branchId = req.body.branchId;
```

and also another things... So can you show me how I get it? I'm a beginner and I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: do you want to get `branchId` from db or from api `req.body` given by user?

Comment: I want it from `db` but even if i inserted it from `req.body`, it didn't work because of the type of `branchId` i guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let BloodStock = mongoose.model('BloodStock');
let BranchModel = mongoose.model('Branch');
let Branch = new BranchModel();
```

and

```
let bloodType = "some value";
let bloodAvailable = "some value";
let bloodUsed = "some value";
let branchId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(Branch._id);
```

then you can call `create()` method to save it.

```
BloodStock.create({
            bloodType: bloodType,
            bloodAvailable: bloodAvailable,
            bloodUsed: bloodUsed,
            branchId: branchId
        })...
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do it like this :

```js
async function(req, res){
    let newbranch = new Branch({
        branchName: "some value",
        officeTelephone: "some value",
        email: "some value",
        city: "some value",
        subCity: "some value",
        zone: "some value",
        wereda: "some value",
        kebele: "some value"
    });
    let branch = await newbranch.save();
    let branchId = branch._id;

    let newBloodStock = new BloodStock({
        bloodType: "some value",
        bloodAvailable: "some value",
        bloodUsed: "some value",
        branchId: branchId
    });
    let bloodStock = await newBloodStock.save();
    let findBloodStockData = await BloodStock.find({}).populate('branchId').exec()

}
```